# ¿Como pasar por funciones variables a otro html en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-objeto

E estado probando este codigo pero al ejecutar la funcion en el otro html las variables de la funcion pierden los valores

```
//Variables del primer html
    function TravelDAta(form){
        let txtNombre = document.getElementById("txtNombreCompleto");
        let txtID = document.getElementById("txtID");
        let txtPhone = document.getElementById("txtTelp");
        let txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtMail");
        let txtCountry = document.getElementById("countries");
        let txtTypeCoins = document.getElementById("coin");
        let txtTypePay = document.getElementById("paid");
        let txtServiceTime = document.getElementById("service1");
        let txtBank = document.getElementById("txtbanks");
        let txtNewServ = document.getElementById("txtBegin");
        let content = [txtNombre,txtID,txtPhone,txtEmail,txtCountry,txtTypeCoins,txtTypePay,txtServiceTime,txtBank,txtNewServ];
    }
    //variables del segundo html
    function returnNewData(content){
        let newcontent = content;
        register.push(newcontent);
    }
```

Comment: inicializa a `register` => `register = []`

Comment: Cada vez que cargas una página, todo el Javascript se ejecuta desde 0. Si quieres guardar información de una visita previa puedes usar el `localStorage`